# Debian Log In Failure With Correct Password

Tags: debian, login, password

So I have a Debian distro at home (considering getting ubuntu), and I can't login. When I use the correct password is does this thing where it makes it look like it's going to login, and then it redirects to the login screen, but when I use an incorrect password it says "authentication failure". Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Check for errors in `~/.xsession_errors` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. You should be able to still login in via the console (Ctrl+Alt+F1).

Comment: What desktop are you using? You could try switching to a console (Ctrl+Alt+F1 through Ctrl+Alt+F6), login, and type `startkde` (If you are using KDE, if not, leave a comment telling what desktop you are using), then post the errors if there are any.

Comment: Exact same problem in 2021... but i can actually login after retrying the operation 5+ times. Happens in ubuntu, randomly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps your `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, or `.bashrc` contains an error, and makes the shell exit?

If thats the case, use `ctr-alt-F1` to enter the shell. use the command `su - root` to enter a root session, and then use `nano` or `vi` to edit the file that is broken.

Comment: Very possible, I was just editing it, but how can I fix that from the login? Is there a way to access the CLI?

Comment: I can't find my bash profile. I even tried to use the `locate` command. What directories would they be in?

Comment: With Mac OS keyboard that will be ‘CNTR+alt+f3+fn’

Comment: Everyone is adding their own reason but this answer is always true so I'll just comment instead of answering. Basically, I had done `apt install fuse` in an automated script, without knowing that Parallels Desktop had already setup another version of it. It messed up my home folders. So anytime you see that you have autoremovable packages no longer needed, I guess you should be careful with your home folder too.

Answer (score 7):

Had exactly the issue as described. After switching to a console (`Ctrl+Alt+F1` through `Ctrl+Alt+F6`), it appeared that the root folder was completely full (use `df` ). A simple `sudo apt-get clean` did the trick. After confirmation that the drive has space available, go back to login screen using `Ctrl+Alt+F7`).

Comment: This what happen to me after downloading the blockchain data 100+GB in the Debian machine in VM. Had to get new SSD in the case

Comment: While going from Ctrl+Alt+F1 through Ctrl+Alt+F6 follow this link as well https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem from time to time, but the solutions here don't work. I found the following somewhere, but can't find it again, so here it is:

1. Switch to a console with `Ctrl+Alt+F3`;
2. Log in using the console (you are asked for your username and password right away);
3. Type `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` and the password for `sudo`;
4. Go back with `Ctrl+Alt+F7` and proceed normally.

Those are the standard permissions of `/tmp` and I have absolutely no clue why they should be wrong at log in. The only pattern I think I found is that I need to have tired to log in with a wrong password before using the correct one stops working.

Comment: While this might be a solution to *something*, how would the OP accomplish step 2, log in, when they can’t log in?

Comment: Ah, I meant log in using the terminal. The OP can't log in using the graphical interface, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they can't log in at all. When you press `Ctrl+Alt+F3`, you are asked for your username and password before you can do anything else. At least in my case, which can be described exactly as OP described their problem, this works.

Comment: I did see any reference from the OP about a graphical login (it’s not mentioned one way or the other).

Comment: @pochinha you are right, GUI login is not working through its possible to log via the shell

Answer (score 2):

Alternative cause and solution:

In my case, there was a syntax error in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Judging by google results, this is a lot more rare than file permission problems. I found this out through attempting `startx` from the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F2), which pointed me to a log file where it noted the syntax error.