# Why should I login multiple times on Debian to access to my session?

Tags: debian, xorg, login, nvidia, gdm3

I have a similar problem than this one: [*Debian Log In Failure With Correct Password*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62623/debian-log-in-failure-with-correct-password).
Indeed, when I start my computer, GDM ask me to enter my password and I have to do it multiple times (three or four in a row) to access to my session.

Why don't GDM log me directly? Is there a configuration problem?

Here is my `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Oct  8 08:17:29 my_desktop polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c3 (system bus name :1.31 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Oct  8 08:17:41 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=pierre
Oct  8 08:17:41 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=pierre
Oct  8 08:17:41 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user pierre by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:17:41 my_desktop systemd-logind[760]: New session 5 of user pierre.
Oct  8 08:17:41 my_desktop systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user pierre by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:17:42 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user pierre
Oct  8 08:17:49 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=pierre
Oct  8 08:17:49 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=pierre
Oct  8 08:17:49 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user pierre by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:17:49 my_desktop systemd-logind[760]: New session 7 of user pierre.
Oct  8 08:17:50 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user pierre
Oct  8 08:17:56 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=pierre
Oct  8 08:17:56 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=pierre
Oct  8 08:17:56 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user pierre by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:17:56 my_desktop systemd-logind[760]: New session 8 of user pierre.
Oct  8 08:17:57 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user pierre
Oct  8 08:18:01 my_desktop CRON[2257]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:18:01 my_desktop CRON[2258]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:18:01 my_desktop CRON[2258]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct  8 08:18:02 my_desktop CRON[2257]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct  8 08:18:06 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=pierre
Oct  8 08:18:06 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=pierre
Oct  8 08:18:06 my_desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user pierre by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:18:06 my_desktop systemd-logind[760]: New session 11 of user pierre.
Oct  8 08:18:08 my_desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[2858]: failed to unlock login keyring on startup
Oct  8 08:18:16 my_desktop polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:11 (system bus name :1.93 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Oct  8 08:18:23 my_desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[2858]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Unprotected/1, but it's already registered
Oct  8 08:18:23 my_desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[2858]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Unprotected/1, but it's already registered
Oct  8 08:19:01 my_desktop CRON[3835]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:19:01 my_desktop CRON[3836]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:19:01 my_desktop CRON[3836]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct  8 08:19:02 my_desktop CRON[3835]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct  8 08:19:41 my_desktop systemd-logind[760]: Removed session 5.
Oct  8 08:19:50 my_desktop systemd-logind[760]: Removed session 7.
Oct  8 08:19:57 my_desktop systemd-logind[760]: Removed session 8.
Oct  8 08:20:01 my_desktop CRON[4605]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user smmsp by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:20:01 my_desktop CRON[4606]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:20:01 my_desktop CRON[4607]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  8 08:20:01 my_desktop CRON[4607]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct  8 08:20:01 my_desktop CRON[4605]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user smmsp
Oct  8 08:20:02 my_desktop CRON[4606]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

My desktop environment is Gnome 3 and I'm using Debian 9:

```
> uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19)
```

---

**EDIT:** Here is the result of `journalctl -b`:

```
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]: Fatal server error:
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]: (EE) Cannot open log file "/home/pierre/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-2184.log"
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]:          at http://wiki.x.org
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]:  for help.
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:44 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2182]: Unable to run X server
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]: Fatal server error:
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]: (EE) Cannot open log file "/home/pierre/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-2215.log"
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]:          at http://wiki.x.org
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]:  for help.
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:52 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2213]: Unable to run X server
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]: Fatal server error:
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]: (EE) Cannot open log file "/home/pierre/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-2243.log"
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]:          at http://wiki.x.org
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]:  for help.
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]: (EE)
Oct 17 08:51:59 my_desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2241]: Unable to run X server
```

However, I have permission to write in that directory:

```
> ll /home/pierre/.local/share/xorg/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 pierre users     4 Oct 17 08:52 ./
drwx------ 27 pierre users    32 Oct 17 14:38 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 pierre users 26361 Oct 17 08:52 Xorg.1.log
-rw-r--r--  1 pierre users 27654 Oct 16 17:56 Xorg.1.log.old
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
I'm still stuck with my issue. Maybe the log of Xorg can be more useful: https://pastebin.com/raw/05iTLdfm