# Can't login with normal user with GUI

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, login, gui

I tried to log in to my user through my gnome desktop manager with valid credentials. It doesn’t tell me "you have bad credentials", it just doesn’t let me in.

I can log in with the root user and I created another user and I can log in with that too, but not this user. It leads me to a blank screen with a cursor blinking in it and after 5 to 7 seconds I get back to the part where I should enter my username.

1. I checked the `.Xauthority` permissions are referring to my user.
2. I can log in to my user with the terminal but not the GUI.
3. After I enter my username and password, it creates the session for my user but closes it after like 5 seconds and logs me out.
4. After logging in to a tty, I can `startx` to go into the GUI.

my `/var/log/auth.log`

```
May  4 14:00:34  gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
May  4 14:00:34  gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user faran by (uid=0)
May  4 14:00:34  systemd-logind[524]: New session 29 of user faran.
May  4 14:00:34  systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user faran by (uid=0)
May  4 14:00:41  gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user faran
May  4 14:00:41  systemd-logind[524]: Session 29 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
May  4 14:00:41  systemd-logind[524]: Removed session 29.
May  4 14:00:48  gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
May  4 14:00:51  gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
```

I also set another user home folder to my special users (the one that I can't log in with) home folder, and I can't log in to that user either, so I guess there is a problem with my home folder and configs inside. The other direction doesn't work -- if I set my special user home folder to another user home folder I can't log in.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I did not have the same issue but a very similar one. Differences are: os (debian 11) and auth.log did not show last two lines.

So, to troubleshoot I was comparing the file `.profile` with the original content (it can be compared with the file of a new user i.e. `diff /home/YOUR_USER/.profile /home/CREATED_USER/.profile`).

Since `.profile` is loaded at login time, any error will abort the process and place the user in the login screen again.

If that was not useful, perhaps these other questions might help you:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231410/cant-log-in-on-ubuntu-20-04
- [Debian Log In Failure With Correct Password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62623/debian-log-in-failure-with-correct-password)